# Get Data Failed, Mapel Id Not Found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

**I have an EndpointLocalDatasource to store the id, where in GetsoalRemoteDatasource I will retrieve the id on the Endpoint, but what appears is**

```
flutter: {"success":true,"message":"Get Data Berhasil","data":[{"id":3,"nama":"matematika","user_id":8,"finish_date":null,"finish_time":null,"created_at":"2023-12-06T07:48:26.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-12-06T07:48:26.000000Z"},{"id":4,"nama":"Sejarah","user_id":8,"finish_date":"2023-12-14", "finish_time":"20:59:00", "created_at":"2023-12-06T07:49:51.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-12-06T12:58:12.000000Z"}]}
flutter: [3, 4]
flutter: {"success":false,"message":"Get Data Gagal, Id Matkul Tidak Ditemukan","data":null}
```

**here is my code in EndpointRemoteDatasource** **:**

```
class EndpointLocalDatasource {
  Future<bool> saveDataEndpoint(EndpointResponseModel data) async {
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final result = await pref.setString('endpoint', data.toJson());
    return result;
  }

  Future<List<int>> getIdEndpoint() async {
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final jsonString = pref.getString('endpoint') ?? '';

    try {
      final endpointModel = EndpointResponseModel.fromJson(jsonString);

      if (endpointModel.data.isNotEmpty) {
        List<int> allIds = [];
        for (var item in endpointModel.data) {
          allIds.add(item.id);
        }
        return allIds;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error parsing JSON: $e');
    }

    return [];
  }
}
```

**Here is my GetSoalRemoteDatasource code :**

```
class GetsoalRemoteDatasource {
  Future<Either<String, GetSoalResponseModel>> getSoal() async {
    final userId = await EndpointLocalDatasource().getIdEndpoint();
    debugPrint(userId.toString()); // here userId is still read [3, 4]
    final header = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${await LoginLocalDatasource().getToken()}'
    };
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('${GlobalVariables.baseUrl}/api/guru/mapel/$userId}'), 
      headers: header,
    );
      debugPrint(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Right(GetSoalResponseModel.fromJson(response.body));
    } else {
      return const Left('Server error');
    }
  }
}
```

**why when calling userId in here Uri.parse('${GlobalVariables.baseUrl}/api/guru/mapel/$userId}'), instead what appears is flutter: {"success":false, "message": "Get Data Failed, Subject Id Not Found", "data":null} ?**